# Advice: no reply after the 2nd interview

Tags: phd, interview

I have applied for a research position.  During the second interview, they told me the contact me at the beginning or at the end next week to discuss details.

“Next week” has passed (it was last week). Today is Wednesday.

I need your advice. Should I write an email and ask why they didn’t arrange the 3rd interview? Can my email change their mind about their decision? Should i wait their email? If not,  how to write a follow- interview email  politely?

EDIT 1
**Follow up email**

It was a pleasure meeting you and your team!
Thank you for taking the time to interview me.
I wanted to quickly follow-up and see if there are any updates on the phd position I interviewed for on 01.06. I’m very excited about this opportunity and look forward to learning about any next steps. If you need any more information from me, please let me know, and I’ll happily provide it. I have requested a recommendation letter from my employer, if you need it I will be happy to send it

Comment: This is extremely common. They may be busy (exam times in many places, you may the the second option and they are waiting for the first to respond, etc. Wait a couple of days more, and then send a polite email with more or less "I enjoyed the interview thansk a lot, is there any news on this". No one will take it badly. Don't assume they have not selected you though, they may just be slow for unrelated reasons.

Comment: Unfortunately it is common in the academia world  https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/178850/should-i-contact-the-pi-on-monday-after-the-postdoc-interview-held-on-friday-to

Answer (score 3):

No, don't ask them why they didn't schedule another interview. No, don't try to "change their minds" in an email. Any of that will be counterproductive.

You can send an email, but simply ask for an update on the state of your application. You may get an answer, or not. But avoid any hint of "pressure".

Comment: It's been 3 weeks since my second interview with team. Can i send a follow up email? Could you please have a look at my draft ( EDIT 1 )? What do you think about it?